# why i can't run my project on android studio when i import realm database?

Tags: android

Unable to find method

'com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.getDefaultConfig()Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/DefaultConfig;'.

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your pos_android.gradle file is correct, no need to modify it.

Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of the application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

That is your app.gradle file should look like this.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android' //this should be first line
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
 compileSdkVersion 27
 defaultConfig {
     ...
 }
 buildTypes {
     ...
 }

 dependencies {
 ...
 }
}
```

Follow the instructions as mentioned in [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) Or take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52247041/6393514).

Comment: when i move realm to the top of the application level it error "'com.android.application' or 'com.android.library' plugin required."

Answer (score 0):

Ref : [How to install realm as a gradle dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028087/how-to-install-realm-as-a-gradle-dependency)

First of all copy the class path dependency to build.gradle file(Project):-

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.1"
    }
}
```

Finally, copy and paste the following code on top of build.gradle(App) :-

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Note:- For more please check https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/